# Failed to flutter build ipa Because Target release_unpack_ios failed

Tags: ios, flutter

I try to `flutter build ipa` as usual.
But, I can't build suddenly.
Error log below

```
Error (Xcode): Target release_unpack_ios failed: Exception: Binary
/Users/[my-user-name]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-[random text]/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/Rel
ease-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Flutter does not contain . Running lipo -info:


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

I tried to 2 options.

1. developer cache of mac storage deleted
2. cache clean in flutter project like this

- `rm ios/Podfile`
- `pod update`
- `flutter clean`

Why this happened?
Hope your advice, thanks.

Comment: how did you solved?